# How to deal with specific data columns in a Clustering Algorithm

Tags: data-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset having

- two id columns
- 16 input columns
- 3 output columns 
  Out of these some columns have very sparse data (85% NaN) as they only have data for specific values of ID_2. How do i deal with them while making a clustering algorithm (i am applying k means)

   first question here so please be kind

Earlier I had tried to remove the columns with over 85% NaN values. but this lead to incorrect results as the data from those columns are apparently important. Also fitting them with a mean value leads to highly biased results as almost all the columns have a specific value